# Calculate difference in numeric values

Tags: php, algorithm, count, numeric

I have two variables:

```
$low = 0;
$high = 100;
```

Using these two variables, I want to set 4 new variables, starting from the low value going to the high. So in this case, it would be:

```
$low = 0;
$value_1 = 20;
$value_2 = 40;
$value_3 = 60;
$value_4 = 80;
$high = 100;
```

What calculation can I do to achieve this? The `$low` and `$high` values were set just to help explain my question. These two values are set by the user.

Comment: do you want to set the value between 0 and 100

Comment: @user3647254 The problem is that the $low and $high count is set by the user, so I don't know what they are set to. It could be for example $low=50 and $high=1498...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the distance between $low and $high to be equally distributed between four values.

I think the algorithm is pretty self explanatory in the code below...

```
<?php
$low = 0; //substitute user entry
$high = 100; //substitute user entry
$difference = $high - $low;
$increment = $difference/5; 
//we use 5 because we need four divisible values, you can change this
//based on how many incremental values you want.
$step = $low;
echo $low."<br>";
for($x=0;$x<4;$x++)
{
  $step+=$increment;
  echo $step."<br>";
}
echo $high."<br>";
?>
```

For `$low = 0, $high = 100` - this will print:

```
0
20
40
60
80
100
```

For `$low = 57, $high = 94` - this will print:

```
57
64.4
71.8
79.2
86.6
94
```

For `$low =222, $high = 1000` - this will print:

```
222
377.6
533.2
688.8
844.4
1000
```

You can `round()` as you need. Also make sure that you do basic validation for $low and $high, for eg, that $low is actually smaller than $high etc.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your updates, maybe [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) is enough for your needs:

```
$low = 0; $high = 100; $steps = 5;

$value = range($low, $high, ($high-$low)/$steps);

print_r($value);
```

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => 0
>       [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) => 20
>       [2](https://eval.in/280211) => 40
>       [3] => 60
>       [4] => 80
>       [5] => 100
>   )

[See test at eval.in](https://eval.in/280211) (*link expires soon*)

Comment: OP asked for the variables not the array

Comment: I wonder if your or @raidenace's approach is better in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just run a loop and create a variable. Use the code below

```
<?php
$low = 0;
$high = 100;
$step = 20;

$f = 0;
for($i=$low; $i<=$high; $i+=$step){
  ${"variable_$f"} = $i;
$f++;
}
echo $variable_1;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The problem is that the $low and $high count is set by the user, so I don't know what they are set to. It could be for example $low=50 and $high=1498... so it would not work to have a set $step, right?

Comment: Actually i am bit confused can you post the values of $low, $high and $step and the desired output

Comment: Sorry I did not explain properly. For example, the values can be set to $low=50 and $high=1498. This means that our script must calculate the $step by using these two values AND THEN calculate the 4 values we are after. Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to make an array
`$low`, `&high` and `$step` can have any value

```
$low = 0;        
$high = 100;

$step = 20;

$var = array();

for($x = 0; $x < $high/$step; $x++) {
     if($x == $low || $x == $high) {
         continue;
     } else {
         $var[$x] = $x * $step;
     }
 }
```

The array will look like

```
Array ( [1] => 20 [2] => 40 [3] => 60 [4] => 80 )
```

Comment: The problem is that the $low and $high count is set by the user, so I don't know what they are set to. It could be for example $low=50 and $high=1498...

Comment: $low, &high and $step can have any value

Answer (score 0):

I would subtract $high from $low and then devided by number of varibles I want to have. Example:

$low = 50;
$high = 1498;

I want to create 4 variables.

($high - $low) / 4 = 362

Now I know the $step and I can do the for loop

for ($low; $low =< $high; $low + $step) {}

Answer (score 0):

you can write the code like this simple and specific :

```
`<?php`
        $low = 0;
        $high = 100;
        $stepInc = 20;
        $i ;
        for ($i=$low; $i <= $high ; $i+=$stepInc) { 
            echo $i . "<br>";
        }
?>

and the out will be:

0
20
40
60
80
100
```